# Configure htaccess to bypass direct links to CSS and Javascript Files

Tags: javascript, php, css, apache, .htaccess

I am currently developing a mini framework which uses a htaccess doc which redirects all traffic from the public folder to another folder. But Ive realized that it also redirects all direct links to images, css and scripts.

I am not that familiar with htaccess code, how can I put those exceptions in this htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cmd=$1 [PT,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: move lines 3-4 above line 2 Or move line 2 below 4

Comment: Have you tried the first `RewriteRule` at the end ?

Comment: @Dagon same thing...different ways...

Comment: the point is rules are read in order, you want to exclude exisiting files FIRST

Comment: @Dagon Ive tried it and it creates a 500 Internal server error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot route everything to `public/` and `index.php` at the same time. You probably want this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```